# How to fix 'ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 2: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: wrong type' error in RaspberryPi

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I would like to create a C++ library(.so) and use it in Python.
But as you can see, the C++ function argument is fixed-size array.
When creating a python source as shown below, 
lib.ShiftRows.argypes=types.c_void_p, ?]
What type of data should I put in the "?" section?

And how do Python declare an array in order to declare the same array variable as c++ when actually using the above class?

AES.cpp:

```
void AESS::ShiftRows( char state[0x04][0x04]) {
int i, j, k, tmp;

for (i = 0; i<4; i++) {
    for (j = 4 - i; j<4; j++) {
        tmp = state[i][0];
        for (k = 0; k<4 - 1; k++) {
            state[i][k] = state[i][k + 1];
        }
        state[i][3] = tmp;
    }
  }
}

extern "C"
{
    AESS* AESS_new(){return new AESS();}
    void ShiftRows(AESS* aes,  char state[0x04][0x04]) {aes->ShiftRows(state);}
}
```

AESClass.py:

```
import ctypes

lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./libAESS.so')

class AESS():
    def __init__(self):
        lib.AESS_new.argtypes = []
        lib.AESS_new.restype = ctypes.c_void_p        

        lib.ShiftRows.argtypes=[ctypes.c_void_p , ?]
        lib.ShiftRows.restype= ctypes.c_void_p

        self.obj=lib.AESS_new()

    def ShiftRows(self, state):
        lib.ShiftRows(self.obj, state)
```

AES.py:

```
import numpy as np
from AESClass import AESS

state = np.zeros((4,4))

aes = AESS()

aes.ShiftRows(state)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [[Python 3.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes) (**Arrays** section) out.

You could do something like:

- *AESClass.py*:

  ```
  CharArr4 = ctypes.c_char * 4
  CharArr4Arr4 = CharArr4 * 4

  class AESS():

  # ...

          lib.ShiftRows.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p , CharArr4Arr4]
  ```
- *AES.py* (use of [[SciPy]: numpy.ctypeslib.**as_array**(*obj, shape=None*)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.ctypeslib.html#numpy.ctypeslib.as_array)):

  ```
  import numpy as np
  from AESClass import AESS, CharArr4Arr4


  state_arr = CharArr4Arr4()  # Initialize the 4 X 4 array to 0
  aes = AESS()
  aes.ShiftRows(state_arr)

  state = np.ctypeslib.as_array(state_arr)
  ```

  or the other way around:

  ```
  # ...
  state = np.zeros((4, 4), dtype=np.int8)
  # ...
  aes.ShiftRows(np.ctypeslib.as_ctypes(state))
  ```

Comment: How do I substitute hexadecimal for state_arr[0][0]?




I tried 'state_arr[0][0]=hex(10)' but error occured.
error is 'TypeError: an integer is required'.
so I tried c_int, c_byte, c_long etc... but not worked

Comment: like you would normally operate with *hex* numbers: `state_arr[0][0] = 0x0A` (which has the value of 10). *hex* returns a string.

Comment: When the array is printed, it is output in decimal.
I want to put a hex value rather than a decimal value in an array.
Is there a way to put a Hexa value in an array?

Comment: You're making a big confusion here. The array has some values. Let's take one of them for example: *11*. In *base10* it's represented as *11*, while in *base16* it's represented as *B* (or in **base8** as *13*), but **it's the same number**. By default (it's normal since humans think in *base10*). Anyway, printing doesn't have anything to do with your previous comment. If you want to print a value in *hex* print it in hex, but that wouldn't change it.

Comment: I know what you're talking about.
Is it not possible to put "W" in the CharArr4 array of the AES.py?
I tried, but the error "an integer is required" appears.

Comment: You need to use *bytes* **not** *str* so use `b"W"`.